# HTML page change when redirecting to different mapping in rest controller

Tags: javascript, html, spring, rest

I got index.html page under mapping http://localhost:8080/ with "a" tag that is link to http://localhost:8080/items. I also have rest controller method as you can see below. My question is how can I change not only document.location to http://localhost:8080/items but also html page from index.html to items-list.html for example. So when i send GET request in Postman http://localhost:8080/items i receive json with each item and browser will display items-list.html page. Should i write somehow .click(function() to receive json data, save it in variable and after that use inner function to change html page?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.idx').click(function(){
         document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/items";
     });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To do list app</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Welcome to Todo List Application</h1>
        <a class="idx">List</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
@GetMapping("/items")
Iterable<TodoItem> items() {

    return todoItemRepository.findAll() ;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "details")
private String details;

@Column(name = "deadline")
private LocalDate deadline;

public TodoItem() {}

public TodoItem(String title, String details, LocalDate deadline) {
    this.title = title;
    this.details = details;
    this.deadline = deadline;
}
```

}

Comment: `but also html page from index.html to items-list.html for example` sounds like your controller should send back HTML instead? Not sure how best to answer this, since it really depends on whether you want your backend to send documents or just data.

Comment: I want controller to return json object as i want to keep it restful but also i want to simply replace html page as i don't want to dive into react/angular etc.

Comment: In that case you want to 1. `return false;` at the end of the click handler function if you decide to add an `href` attribute to the link 2. `$.getJSON("/items", function (items) { ... })`  3. build the list and `$("body div").append(it);`

Comment: Chris can you please help me with that function? I added div (from items-list.html file) that will hold todoItem title and details in <td>. I also added snippet with entity model. My goal is to go to http://localhost:8080/items , append json data to items-list.html and display it.

Comment: Again, that doesn't make sense. If by "going to" http://localhost:8080/item you mean "clicking a link that leads there", the server is supposed to send back a full HTML document. If you merely want to load the list items from that endpoint, there won't be any `items-list.html` because where is it supposed to be coming from? You say your server only sends back data, so any new HTML on the client has to be generated on the fly. If you're asking how to build and insert an HTML table based off loaded JSON, please refer to existing questions that show how to do this.

Comment: So i understand that if my controller is returning json objects then the only way to display it is manipulating core index.html (for example changing its whole layout via JS/JQuery)? if thats the case does it require big amount of understanding such frameworks like react/Vue etc. or thats only few commands to replace current body?

Comment: You don't need React or any other framework; you will have to build a table though. jQuery makes that pretty easy. React isn't that hard though; here's a to do list example: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx